# Where do I get a list of javascript functions along with which browser it's supported in?

Tags: javascript

There are some JS functions that are IE specific. I am working on an application which has cross browser compatibility as a mandatory requirement. Before I use a JS function, I would like to know which browsers support it. Is there an online resource that can help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350179/web-browser-javascript-support-reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/)

You should consider buying his (PPK's) book (I am not on a commission), as it encourages you to use defensive coding with your javascript, so that you have code that detects objects, not browsers. This way of working changes the way you write javascript (even before you get to frameworks), so that the code is easier to maintain and develop.

Some of the other answers point to W3Schools, which has always been where I go to try stuff out when I'm working on front end stuff, it is very useful.

The other thing that I tend to do when I'm on a Javascript mission is to use Aptana for developing. This has some degree of intellisense that also indicates which mainstream browsers support the available functions. I think they still have a free version which will do the job in most cases.

Someone also mentioned that this question may be a duplicate, but sometimes the words used to ask the question make such a difference to how it is later found, even with the powerful searches we have available.

Hope this helps.

Comment: quirksmode.org is my go to place for js browser compatibility issues. ppk does some good work.

Answer (score 3):

[The spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) is your friend. [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is also quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref

Answer (score 0):

I would check http://www.w3schools.com/JS/default.asp

Comment: w3schools is useful, but it is **not** a W3C site; that would be w3.org.